# jquery dialog zindex increases each time it opens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js for the jquery dialog box.

Following is the code to open:

```
    $('#userDetLink').click(function (e) {
            $('#userDet').dialog('open');
        });

    $('#userDet').dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            //do nothing
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            //do nothing
        },
        width: 470,
        modal: false,
        zIndex: 9999
    });
```

On clicking the link (userDetLink) it opens the dialog box. On each click of the link, it increases the zindex by 1(10000, 10001, 10002,...), though i set the zindex of jquery dialog to 9999.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this:

```
$('#userDet').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        //do nothing
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        //do nothing
    },
    width: 470,
    modal: false,
    zIndex: 9999,
    stack: false
});
```

Comment: I update my answer, here is a better solution (set stack parameter to false fix the issue) :)

Comment: You need to check the dev console after opening and closing the dialog several times. The z-index continues to increase every time which is the OP's problem. All your demo shows is the original zIndex option which is set on initialization and doesn't change.

Comment: -1 your solution doesn't work @Prasad soultions works perfect

Comment: version 1.10 removed support for zIndex

Answer (score 1):

In your open parameter for the dialog you can explicity set the z-index of the dialog via jQuery's css() function. I tried getting the zIndex option of the dialog to change the value every time it opened, but it appears to only set the value upon initialization.

jQuery:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
     $(".ui-dialog").css("z-index",9999);
},
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QsBqy/1/)**.